# Programmatically show cell signal strength and wifi indicators in windows phone 8 system tray ?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I run my windows phone 8 app, the system tray only shows the clock and battery indicators. In some cases, I'd like to show the cell signal strength and the wifi indicators for a few seconds, in order to remind the user that s/he's offline.

The only way I can do this currently is when the user taps on the System Tray area, but I'd like to show those programmatically. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible, but you could show it on your app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Right now, I see two issues with doing it myself: First, this feels like reinventing the wheel. Second, if the user taps the system tray area while I'm showing those icons, they will appear twice, creating confusion for the user.